# Powershell Format-Table still resulting in list, can't get it in table form

Tags: powershell

I have a script to get items from a list, write values for each item, and all I want to do is pipe this into a table. I have tried Format-Table, Format-Table - Force,Select-Object then Format-Table, and it isn't working, the results just display in a list no matter what.

```
#CAML Query to Filter List Items
$Query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyChoice' /><Value Type='Choice'>Text Two</Value> 
</Eq></Where></Query></View>"

#Get All List Items matching given query
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $Query

#Loop through each Item
Write-host -f Green "Number of List Items Found:"$ListItems.Count
$output = 
ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{  
    Write-Output "Id :" $ListItem["ID"]
    Write-Output "FileLeafRef :" $ListItem["FileLeafRef"]
    Write-Output "MySecurity :" $ListItem["MySecurity"]
}
$Output | Format-Table -Property ID, FileLeafRef, MySecurity | Out-File 
"C:\wherever\File4.csv"
```

How it shows up now when I run that script (example of 2 list items):

Id:
1
FileLeafRef:
MyFile.docx
MySecurity:
Internal
Id:
2
FileLeafRef:
MySecondFile.png
MySecurity:
Private

I can't really add a Table here, even with Html... but essentially I just want each list item to be a row, and I want the columns: ID, FileLeafRef, MySecurity across the top.

Comment: Can you add a short example of the output your code currently generates, and what you’d like it to look like instead?

Comment: @mclayton - did my best to add a bit of an example in the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, PowerShell defaults to tabular/table view for results of 4 columns and below. You are only asking for 3. So, no need for that Format-Table at all. Also, Out-File does not generate a Csv format. It's plain text.

This...

```
#Loop through each Item
Write-host -f Green "Number of List Items Found:"$ListItems.Count
$output = 
ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{  
    Write-Output "Id :" $ListItem["ID"]
    Write-Output "FileLeafRef :" $ListItem["FileLeafRef"]
    Write-Output "MySecurity :" $ListItem["MySecurity"]
}
$Output | Format-Table -Property ID, FileLeafRef, MySecurity | Out-File 
"C:\wherever\File4.csv"
```

... is the wrong approach to get your end results. You'd never use Format-Table to create a file this way. Format-Table is for screen output.

So, try this...

```
#Loop through each Item
Write-host -f Green "Number of List Items Found:"$ListItems.Count
ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{  
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Id          = "$ListItem['ID']"
        FileLeafRef = "$ListItem[FileLeafRef]"
        MySecurity  = "$ListItem['MySecurity']"
    } | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\wherever\File4.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Example with results:

```
#Loop through each Item
Write-host -f Green "Number of List Items Found:"$(Get-Process).Count
ForEach($ListItem in (Get-Process))
{  
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Id          = $ListItem.Id
        FileLeafRef = $ListItem.Handles
        MySecurity  = $ListItem.ProcessName
    } | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\temp\File4.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\temp\File4.csv'
# Results
<#

Id    FileLeafRef MySecurity             
--    ----------- ----------             
7236  204         aesm_service           
2144  476         ApplicationFrameHost   
21000 150         AppVShNotify           
...
#>
```

Yet, if you are saying that you want a formatted/tabular text file as a report, then this...

```
#Loop through each Item
Write-host -f Green "Number of List Items Found:"$(Get-Process).Count
$ListReport = ForEach($ListItem in (Get-Process))
{  
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Id          = $ListItem.Id
        FileLeafRef = $ListItem.Handles
        MySecurity  = $ListItem.ProcessName
    }
}
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\temp\File4.txt' -InputObject $ListReport
Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\File4.txt'
# Results
<#

   Id FileLeafRef MySecurity             
   -- ----------- ----------             
 7236         204 aesm_service           
 2144         476 ApplicationFrameHost   
21000         150 AppVShNotify           
...
#>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, sorry I should have mentioned that I tried Export-csv which also gave me a list. Your first suggestion finally worked!

Comment: No worries. Gald to assist. Just remember, Write-* is really about just sending output to the screen. Format-* same deal. Out to a file, csv, txt, html, xml, json, et al is always about the object/properties. Note, you can send screen formatted text to a file using a few approaches, but not really needed in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with

```
$output = ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{  
    Write-Output "Id :" $ListItem["ID"] 
    Write-Output "MyRetention :" $ListItem["MyRetention"]
    Write-Output "FileLeafRef :" $ListItem["FileLeafRef"]
    Write-Output "MySecurity :" $ListItem["MySecurity"]
}
```

Get rid of it, you are overwriting your nice list of objects with that.

Output the objects directly (use `Export-Csv` for CSV output, not `Out-File`):

```
$ListItems | Export-Csv "C:\wherever\File4.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

You can use `Select-Object` to reduce them to certain fields:

```
$Output = $ListItems | Select-Object ID, MyRetention, FileLeafRef, MySecurity
$Output | Export-Csv "C:\wherever\File4.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Of course you could write a singular `Get-PnPListItem | Select-Object | Export-Csv` pipeline, but sometimes it's easier to read if you use intermediary variables and break it up over multiple lines.

Comment: I still only get a list with both of your cmdlets. By replacing the output section and using your first code suggestion, I get one column full of weird values like "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AttachmentCollection";;;;"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType";;"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DlpPolicyTip";;;" and none of the fields I actually want. 
If I use the 2nd cmdlet, I also get a list - not a table, and only the Id and ";;;"

Comment: Also I have triev using the CAML <ViewFields> reference instead and that doesn't display the fields. I have a separate question for that: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284013/caml-query-for-sharepoint-online-viewfields-not-working